# Understanding the definition Fock space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

In my lecture we defined the Fock space as follows:

Let $\mathfrak{h}_1,\mathfrak{h}_2,\dots $ be a sequence of separable Hilbert spaces. Let $\mathcal{H}_N=\mathfrak{h}_1\otimes \dots \otimes \mathfrak{h}_N$ and $\mathcal{H}_0:= \mathbb{C}$. Then
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{F}:= \bigoplus_{N=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{H}_N
\end{equation}
is called Fock space.

I asked myself why we have to set $\mathcal{H}_0:= \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I don't actually know the answer, but since quantum states are only defined up to a complex number presumably all states in $\mathcal H_0$ are in the same equivalence class and so physically there is only one physically unique state in the zero particle space.

Comment: Well, $\mathcal{H}_0$ is a one-dimensional (complex) vector space. Hence, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over itself (i.e. over the field of complex numbers).

Answer (score 1):

The no-particle vacuum state is one dimensional. Any one-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: thank you very much!